# insert every row of an Excel spreadsheet into a database in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, excel, database, insert

I know this can be done with any programmatic language like Python that interacts with both databases and Excel spreadsheets. BUT,

Is there any query in MySQL that can insert every row of an Excel spreadsheet into a database table?

Comment: MySQL cannot access XLS/XLSX. Save your file to .CSV then import your data with LOAD DATA.

Answer (score 0):

To answer question as stated, no there is no query in MySQL importing from an excel sheet